# How to dynamically generate script code in html page based on environment?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have an asp.net application, where I need to add a script in the  section of my html, and a value in that script needs to change based on the environment  (TEST, QA etc..).  For simplicity lets just say this is my script, where DisplayValue is the value that needs to be dynamic:

```
<head>
    <script>
        alert("Hello World! Value='" + DisplayValue + "'");
    </script>
</head>
```

This is an asp.net application, but there is no corresponding .aspx file, just plain old html.  Is it possible to read the value from the web.config?  Some other way I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a separate script file for each environment.  Then, based off the url of the page, determine which environment I am running in and dynamically load the correct script.

```
<script>
    function loadJS(url, async = true) {
        let scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
        scriptElement.setAttribute("src", url);
        scriptElement.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        scriptElement.setAttribute("async", async);
        document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
        //success 
        scriptElement.addEventListener("load", () => {
            console.log("Script file loaded.")
        });
        //error
        scriptElement.addEventListener("error", (ev) => {
            console.log("Error loading script file", ev);
        });
    }

    var url = window.location.href.toUpperCase();
    if (url.indexOf("WWWQA.") >= 0) {
        //Load script for QA environment
        loadJS("Scripts/QA-SCRIPT.js", true);
    }
    else if (url.indexOf("WWW.") >= 0) {
        //Load script for PROD environment
        loadJS("Scripts/PROD-SCRIPT.js", true);
    }
</script>
```